# Main method incorrectly displays class string?

Tags: java, string, class, methods, subclass

I'm writing a program that provides the final bill for a stay at a hotel with parameters for Room #, # of guests, duration of stay, and the price per person per night.

I have the math correct in my BBRoom Class however it doesn't seem to take and process the information in the class parameters?

Driver Class:

```
public class BedAndBreakfastDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //float price, int rmNum, int numOccupants, int duration
    //or
    //int rmNum, int numOccupants, int duration, float price

    BBRoom Smith;

    Smith = new BBRoom(29.95, 16, 1, 5);

    System.out.println(Smith);

}
```

}

BBRoom Class:

```
public class BBRoom {

final int MAXCAP = 4;
final int MINCAP = 1;
final int MINSTAY = 1;

int room;
int persons;
int nights;
double cost;
double surcharge;
double cleanUp;
double cottageCost;

NumberFormat fmt1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

BBRoom(double price, int rmNum, int numOccupants, int duration){}


BBRoom( int rmNum, int numOccupants, int duration, double price){}

       private int getRoomNumber(int rmNum){
           room = rmNum;       
           return room;
       }

       private int getPersons(int numOccupants){
           if (numOccupants < MINCAP){
               persons = MINCAP;
           }if(numOccupants > MAXCAP){
                persons = MAXCAP;
             }else{
               persons = numOccupants;
           }
           return persons;
           }

       private int getNights(int duration){   

           if(duration < MINSTAY){
               nights = MINSTAY;

           }else{

               nights = duration;

           }

           return nights;
       }

       private double setCost(double price){
           return price;

       }
       private double getCost(double price){



         if (persons < 2){
             cost = price*2*nights;
            }else{
             cost = (persons*price*nights);
         }

           return cost;
             }

        private double BBCottage(double cost){

               surcharge =  (12.95*nights);

               cleanUp = 47.99;

               cottageCost = cost+surcharge+cleanUp;

               return cottageCost;

           }

        public String toString(){

               String bill = ("Room Number"+room+"   "+"Guests:"+persons+"   "+"Nights:"+nights+"   "+"Basic Package:"+ fmt1.format(cost)+"   "+"Cottage Upgrade:"+fmt1.format(cottageCost) );
               return bill;
           }

        }
```

For some reason I keep getting the output to display every variable as

"Room Number:0 Guests:0 Nights:0 Basic Package:0.00 Cottage Upgrade:0.00"

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. I'd also prefer to turn my BBCottage method into a subclass but I'm not quite sure how to accomplish that. If I could get some guidance on that as well it would be great!

Comment: Why are your constructors doing absolutely nothing? How would a sane person expect a function call that does nothing, to do something?

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor has an empty body

```
BBRoom(double price, int rmNum, int numOccupants, int duration){} // <<<<<<< nothing going on in {}
```

All relevant fields are initialized to their default value of `0`. Implement the constructor to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually set the values inside BBRoom. Also, the methods getVariable(int something)  should be split into a separate get() and set(int something) methods, because otherwise you're simultaneously getting and setting a variable.

In your toString method, you call values that would be returned from get(), but those are never set.  To fix it, you need to set them inside your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructers need to set initial values.

BBRoom:

```
public class BBRoom {

final int MAXCAP = 4;
final int MINCAP = 1;
final int MINSTAY = 1;

int room;
int persons;
int nights;
double cost;
double surcharge;
double cleanUp;
double cottageCost;

NumberFormat fmt1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

BBRoom(double price, int rmNum, int numOccupants, int duration){
   someInstanceVariable = price;
   room = rmNum;
   persons = numOccupants;
   ..and so on..
}


BBRoom( int rmNum, int numOccupants, int duration, double price){
    ..do the same here..
}

       private int getRoomNumber(int rmNum){
           room = rmNum;       
           return room;
       }

       private int getPersons(int numOccupants){
           if (numOccupants < MINCAP){
               persons = MINCAP;
           }if(numOccupants > MAXCAP){
                persons = MAXCAP;
             }else{
               persons = numOccupants;
           }
           return persons;
           }

       private int getNights(int duration){   

           if(duration < MINSTAY){
               nights = MINSTAY;

           }else{

               nights = duration;

           }

           return nights;
       }

       private double setCost(double price){
           return price;

       }
       private double getCost(double price){



         if (persons < 2){
             cost = price*2*nights;
            }else{
             cost = (persons*price*nights);
         }

           return cost;
             }

        private double BBCottage(double cost){

               surcharge =  (12.95*nights);

               cleanUp = 47.99;

               cottageCost = cost+surcharge+cleanUp;

               return cottageCost;

           }

        public String toString(){

               String bill = ("Room Number"+room+"   "+"Guests:"+persons+"   "+"Nights:"+nights+"   "+"Basic Package:"+ fmt1.format(cost)+"   "+"Cottage Upgrade:"+fmt1.format(cottageCost) );
               return bill;
           }

        }
```

As for separating Cottage into another class:

BBCottage:

```
public class BBCottage {
  public BBCottage(double cost){

           surcharge =  (12.95*nights);

           cleanUp = 47.99;

  }

  public double getCottage() {
     cottageCost = cost+surcharge+cleanUp;

     return cottageCost;
  }
  }
```

**Edit:** I also realized that in your main, you're doing `System.out.println(Smith);`. You have print the method, not Smith. So first of all, I'd change BBRoom to have getters and setters:

```
void setRmNum(int rm) {
    room = rm;
}

int getRmNum() {
    return room;
}
```

Then, in your main, do `System.out.println(Smith.getRmNum());`

Comment: So I made the change to the constructors however the program doesn't seem to be calculating the cost through the getCost method, nor does it check if the number of guests is between 2 and 4?

Comment: Ah I know the issue. You're doing `System.out.println(Smith);`. You need to actually run the methods. So, `System.out.println(Smith.getRoomNumber(2));`. Also, I would get rid of the parameters in these methods. Split it up, so you have setRoomNumber(int rm) and getRoomNumber().